# Change cryptos used in WebRTC browser calls

Tags: android, google-chrome, encryption, webrtc

I am developing a voice / video calling system in which there is browser to browser, Android to Android and Android to browser calling. Although I have managed to get that all working, I have run into a problem with the cryptos being used to encrypt the audio / video packets being sent between two clients. My system requires a certain set of cryptos, and I have managed to get that set working with Android to Android calling. However, the default cryptos being used in WebRTC enabled browsers are significantly weaker than the alternate crypto set being used for Android to Android calling. Thus, I have to "dumb down" the cryptos in the system so that I can have Android to browser calling.

Since I have no access to the code for WebRTC enabled browsers (and definitely cannot modify it) my only recourse is to somehow select or tell the peerconnection object which crypto level / set to use. I swear I have heard of this being done before, but I cannot find where I saw it nor anywhere that talks about doing it. So, I was wondering if anyone knew:

1. Is such a thing possible?
2. If possible, how does one set the cryptos for the call?
3. What cryptos are supported in Chrome and Firefox?

If I am remembering what I saw correctly, it was done somewhere along the lines of passing a JSON looking something like: `{ 'crypto' : 'AES....'}` to the constraints parameter of webkitRTCPeerConnection. However, I could potentially be imagining all of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable DTLS by passing the following to the PeerConnection constructor:

```
{ 'optional': [{'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': 'true'}]}
```

However, that doesn't let you pick the crypto algorithm. For that you could potentially munge the SDP with a different [crypto line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4568#section-4) with the given [SRTP key management parameters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3711#section-8.2). However, I'm not sure offhand if anything other than the default is supported in Chrome. That may be a good question for the [discuss-webrtc](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/discuss-webrtc) list.

Comment: By "munge"-ing the SDP line, do you mean straight up replacing the crypto stuff in the SDP? How would that work? Since Chrome would be expecting packets encrypted with a different set of information?

Comment: "munge"-ing the SDP refers to changing the SDP that is generated and returned by `createOffer` before calling `setLocalDescription` on the local side and before calling `setRemoteDescription` on the remote side (or before sending it to the remote side).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I will write that down to try when I eventually get a moment. Thanks.